# How to listen for followup messages with node.js's "ws" library server-side

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

If someone sends a specific message like "/xyz", I want to listen for a followup message which then I can take action on. I'm trying to do this server-side, not client side.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you're going to want to open a connection to the websocket server in question and listen for messages like so:

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
  console.log('received: %s', message);
});
```

Have a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/websockets/ws

Comment: I'm trying to do all of this server-side